# How to test switch cases in react testin library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Here's my code, the switch statements are not covering even though i am rendering the component and passing the props and mocking the function in the props as well still the coverage is 0%, mostly it is getting stuck at useEffect hook I guess.

I am not allowed to use Enzyme that's why please give me the solution from jest, react testing library only.

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";

import {Row,RowBlock} from "./style-tags";
import {Icon} from "../icon";
import "./utp-toaster.css";
import icon from '../icons/icon-alert-warning.png';

const Message = props => {
    const {
        toasterType,message,
        handleToasterClose,iconPath='',
        showIcon=true,toasterTimeout=null
    } = props;
    let background;
    let toasterIcon;
    let color = "#000"

    useEffect(()=> {
        if(!!toasterTimeout) {
            setTimeout(()=>{
                handleToasterClose()
            },toasterTimeout)
        }
    },[])

    switch(toasterType) {
        case 'WARNING' :
            background = '#ffbc3d';
            toasterIcon = !!iconPath ? iconPath : icon
            break;
        case 'SUCCESS' :
            background = '#00AC3E';
            toasterIcon = !!iconPath ? iconPath : icon
            color = '#fff'
            break;
        case 'INFO' :
            background = '#005b9f';
            toasterIcon = !!iconPath ? iconPath : icon
            color = '#fff'
            break;
        default: 
            background = '#005b9f';
            toasterIcon = !!iconPath ? iconPath : icon
            break;
    }

    return (
        <Row background={background}>
            {showIcon && 
                <RowBlock width = "5%">
                    <div className="toaster-block">
                        {
                            !!toasterIcon &&
                            <img src={toasterIcon} alt="info" />
                        }
                    </div>
                </RowBlock>
            }
            <RowBlock width={`${!showIcon?'95%':'90%'}`}>
                <div className="toaster-block">
                    <p style={{'fontWeight':'bold'}}>{message}</p>
                </div>
            </RowBlock>
            <RowBlock width="5%">
                <div className="toaster-block">
                    <p onClick={handleToasterClose}><Icon name="close" /></p>
                </div>
            </RowBlock>
        </Row>
    )
}


export default Message



import {render, screen} from "@testing-library/react"
import Message from "../Message"
test("test for warning", () => {
    const props = {
        toasterType: 'WARNING',
        message: "warning",
        handleToasterClose: jest.fn(),
        iconPath:'../icons.icon-alert-warning.png',
        showIcon:true,
        toasterTimeout:'9546845'
    } 
    let background;
    let toasterIcon;
    let color = "#000"

    render(<Message {...props} toasterType='WARNING' />)
})
```

Comment: Why pass `toasterType` twice? `props` object & as a custom attribute prop?

Answer (score 0):

You should render the component with the possible values. You can use jest's describe.each not to repeat everything.

Here's an example

```
describe("<Message />", () => {
  describe.each([
    ["WARNING", `background: rgb(255, 188, 61);`],
    ["SUCCESS", `background: rgb(0, 172, 62);`],
    ["INFO", "background: rgb(0, 91, 159)"],
    ["OTHER", "background: rgb(0, 91, 159);"],
  ])("with toasterType = %s", (toasterType, style) => {
    it(`should have styles ${style}`, async () => {
      render(
        <Message
          message={toasterType.toLowerCase()}
          toasterType={toasterType}
        />
      );
      return expect(screen.findByTestId("row")).resolves.toHaveStyle(style);
    });
  });
});
```